# Как передать много записей через Form в Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

Суть проблемы в том, что я начал изучать Laravel и не могу найти информацию, как передать много полей через форму, с последующей валидацией.
Пример формы:

```
<form class="mt-5" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                          @isset($word)
                            action="{{ route('edit.word.update', $word) }}"
                          @else
                            action="{{ route('edit.word.store') }}"
                          @endisset
                    >
                        @csrf

                        @isset($word)
                            @method('PUT')
                        @endisset

                        <table class="table table-responsive-md">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>English</th>
                                <th>Transcription</th>
                                <th>Russian</th>
                                <th>Ukrainian</th>
                                <th>Module</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            @for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="eng[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control"
                                               value="{{ old('eng', isset($word)?$word->eng:null) }}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="transaction[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control"
                                               value="{{ old('transaction', isset($word)?$word->transaction:null) }}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="ru[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control"
                                               value="{{ old('ru', isset($word)?$word->ru:null) }}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="uk[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control"
                                               value="{{ old('uk', isset($word)?$word->uk:null) }}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="category_id[{{ $i }}]" class="form-control"
                                               value="{{ old('category_id', isset($word)?$word->category_id:null) }}"></td>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endfor
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                        <a class="btn btn-secondary mt-4" href="{{ route('edit.modules') }}">Back</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-success  mt-4">Save</button>
                    </form>
```

На выходе получаетс вот такое, но точно знаю что так не правильно.

```
^ array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "Olp8kMQIFoDP9OOvV5YRihcV3FpKIHofxfYk8W7M"
  "eng" => array:2 [▶]
  "transaction" => array:2 [▶]
  "ru" => array:2 [▼
    1 => "www"
    2 => "qqq"
  ]
  "uk" => array:2 [▶]
  "category_id" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

Как правильно это переделать?

Comment: Откуда вы знаете что это неправильно? А как правильно? Читайте [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input) и выясните как данные формы передаются, извлекаются и проверяются в Laravel, и пишите конкретнее ваш вопрос - правильно или неправильно это ваши понятия, о которых мы не имеем представления если вы их не опишите в вопросе.

Comment: Я понял, уже нашел решение, но теперь не могу понять, как передать этот же массив на проверку для выведения ошибок. Например: @error('eng[$i]')